# different between bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.bundle.min.js?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In the download file of bootstrap, we found many files in JS folder. But I want to know that if we use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` then is it necessary to use `bootstrap.min.js`?

Comment: please research before posting https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/contents/#css-files

Answer (score 41):

Both are same but bundle has other js included in it like `popper.js` whereas, bootstrap.min.js only have the minimal js which is required to run the bootstrap.

You can use any one of them to start using bootstrap.

Comment: It is noteworthy that importing `popper.js` is necessary in order to run some Bootstrap component (like dropdown menus). See for instance https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/#js-components